# Python --- Logging error --- AttributeError but can't find where?

Tags: python, logging

Hello I coding a simple looging in python with 2 handlers and 1 formatter and got a AttributeError but can't find where.
Here My code:

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler


#Configuration loggeur
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s :: %(levelname)s :: %(message)s')
file_handler = RotatingFileHandler(filename='activity2.log', mode='a', maxBytes=1000000, backupCount= 2, encoding='utf-8')

file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)

stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
stream_handler.setFormatter(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(stream_handler)

logger.warning('On y va')
```

And here the ouput:

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\scapenv\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1081, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\scapenv\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 925, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'format'
Call stack:
  File "d:/02 - Programmes/08 - Passerelles/HBS/St Julien - GS Nelson Mandela/Py Excel/testlog.py", line 32, in <module>
    logger.warning('On y va')
Message: 'On y va'
Arguments: ()
```

If y have some clues...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Third line starting from the bottom:

```
stream_handler.setFormatter(logging.DEBUG)
```

You are giving `logging.DEBUG` instead of `formatter` as argument.

Fix:

```
stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
```

Comment: Hello thx for the answers but it not it:  setFormatter is for fixing the level the handler take. Here i put logging.DEBUG who is a int of value 10.

Comment: It's definitely should fix your problem.

Comment: @olivier `logging.DEBUG` equals to `10`. Just do `print(loggin.DEBUG)` to see it. That is why you got an error.

Comment: Ok my bad y are right it was the problem thanks you